# Retrieving values from AngularJS service without returning them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I would really appreciate some feed back on how this works? I have a service in which I store some session specific variables such as table sorting choices and more.

The code seems to work fine. However, my question is - how is it possible for me to retrieve these values without returning the actual variable?

Shouldn't I have to use some kind of Getter function? Are they made public some way with the setter method, or am I doing something completely wrong here? Is using *this* some kind of culprit? Or simply my lack of understanding of javascript scoping? :)

Service code:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('sessionService', function () {

  this.searchView = 2; // <-- edited in, forgot this

  return {
    setSearchView: setSearchView
  };

  function setSearchView (searchView) {
    this.searchView = searchView;
  }

});
```

And then we have the controller.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SearchCtrl', function (sessionService) {

  console.log(sessionService.searchView); //undefined

  sessionService.setSearchView(1);

  console.log(sessionService.searchView); // 1 

});
```

Once I've set for example the searchView from the controller, it is possible to just access it as below.

Anything that can help me understand this would be appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to add that this.searchView was actually there form the start, same result in console.log in the controller though.

Comment: The service doesn't have a property named `searchView` until you set it, at which point it is defined and public. If you wanted it to be private, you'd have to use a variable so it is scoped to that function and use getter/setter methods.

Comment: when the service is initialized, searchView IS undefined, it gets its value only after you use setSearchView

Comment: Thanks for your answers, please see my edit. 
this.searchView = 2; was there from the start.

Does this make a difference in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject the service into the controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SearchCtrl', function (sessionService) {
```

you are provided with an **instance** of the service definition function. In other words, your `sessionService` is basically

```
new function () {

  return {
    setSearchView: setSearchView
  };

  function setSearchView (searchView) {
    this.searchView = searchView;
  }

}
```

i.e the function you passed in when you defined the service preceded by new. The **new** means that you are just using it as a constructor function.

---

Now, what do we know about **new** and Javascript constructors - just that if the constructor function returns an object, that's what the left hand side of new is set to. And `this` in the member methods basically refers to that same object.

In short, your service definition is a constructor function. In plain Javascript it would look something like this.

```
function SessionService () {
  return {
    setSearchView: function (searchView) {
       this.searchView = searchView;
    }
  };
}

var sessionService = new SessionService();
```

Notice that I capitalized `SessionService` to indicate that it is a constructor and `sessionService` is in camel case because it is an instance.

---

With this in mind, when you do

```
sessionService.setSearchView(1);
```

you are setting the `searchView` property of the `sessionService` instance to 1. And when you do

```
sessionService.searchView
```

this is the exact same property that you are accessing and you get the value you set.

You could also do `sessionService.searchView` = 1 and it would work as well, since all you are doing is working on the sessionService instance.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, however I actually did have a 
this.searchView = 2; 
from the start, shouldn't that be a property then?

Comment: It would have, IF you hadn't returned anything from the service definition function (knock off the return statement and you'll see it work - you'll have to remove the setSearchView call so that the controller doesn't error out). Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/360067 - what's happening is point 4. - your newly created object (the one you set this.searchView to in the first line) is replaced by the non-primitive object that you return.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I might be dense here.

I can see it works as you say if I replace 
this.searchView = 2; 
with 
var searchView = 2;

So maybe my confusion is more how this.searchView becomes a public property without being explicitly returned... :S

Comment: hm.. I actually meant remove the return, like so - http://jsfiddle.net/xk6v5gaq/.

Comment: Originally, what's actually returned is the what you return (sorry if that sounds confusing :-)) - i.e. a literal object with just one member function setSearchView. When you call setSearchView (of the object), it in turn sets the property searchView on the object. Your first this.searchView = 2 has no impact because the `this` refers to a separate object, that is discarded in favour of the aforesaid literal object (because you do a return in your constructor function)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. The property gets added when the method adds it to the object, kind of?  Thanks for all the help and the examples, I might have to study up a bit on Object prototypes and constructors. :)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what happens! http://speakingjs.com/ is a nice book if you're looking for something in depth.

Answer (score 2):

Service are what are called 'singletons' meaning you can set a variable not directly accessible or returned and it will maintain it's values for the life if the UI. In this case, if you want t be able to access sessionService.searchView, you can do it a few ways:

1) Set a private var searchView and then add a getter function to your return statement:

```
  return {
    setSearchView: setSearchView,
    getSearchView: function() {
        return searchView;
    }
  };
```

2) create the same private variable and then add it to your return statement:

```
var searchView;

return {
    setSearchView: setSearchView,
    searchView: searchView
};
```